# Margin Problem on IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, margins

[The page I am working on can be found here](http://landingdev.fishlist.com/join/).

In IE7, everything in the main content area is being pushed to the left...

Can someone check it out and let me know what's up?

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't have IE7 on this computer, but it looks like you have `float:left` applied to your main `div`

```
#body_container {
 float: left; // try removing this
}
```

**EDIT**

Had another look at the source and the page appears to be rendering in quirks mode in IE7.

Here are few ways to fix that:

1. make sure all your code is valid
2. make sure you are using the right doctype

Details here: [Forcing IE7 into standards rendering mode (not quirks)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946216/forcing-ie7-into-standards-rendering-mode-not-quirks)

Comment: you might also want to add this to the same rule: `margin: 0 auto;`

Comment: @Eric, did you also try the `margin:0 auto;` bit?

Comment: yeah, i put that in there.  the changes are live if you'd like to look

Answer (score 0):

If this is a problem only in IE7, you might wanna try [IE7 compatibility mode](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2008/08/27/introducing-compatibility-view.aspx)